# Switch Layout between different Keyboards

Tags: macos, keyboard, language

I own a MacBook Pro with a German keyboard layout but bought a UK external keyboard because the special characters are much more convenient for coding and LaTeX.

Currently, I have to manually switch between UK and GER keyboard layouts in the menu bar, when I am switching between the internal and external keyboard.

Is there a way to make MacOS always recognise the internal keyboard as German and the external always as UK-layout?

Comment: Not sure if you can set default input sources for specific keyboards, but you could use the standard keyboard shortcut `Control`+`Space` to switch between different language input sources quickly.

Comment: @AVelj thanks. Didn't know about this! Wish apple had done this slightly more elegant but this is sufficient!

Comment: It’s been a keyboard shortcut for as long as I’ve had a Mac (about 15-16 years). I’m sure someone else may assist with some way of recognising different keyboards, but I can’t speak to that.

Answer (score 1):

See this discussion: https://superuser.com/a/1150616.

Direct link for a utility repo: https://github.com/ohueter/autokbisw

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.