# Can I specify the keyboard layout for a single bluetooth device?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I recently bought a new keyboard with another layout than my mac has (mac has qwertz, new keyboard has qwerty). I find it a bit tedious to manually have to switch the keyboard setting globally instead of seamlessly switching between devices and layouts. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Can't you just make it qwertz for both keyboards through some keyboard layout editor? It will just change your bluetooth one since the built-in is already qwertz

Comment: sadly not, because apart from the switch of z and y, the two layouts have other differnces too (umlauts, basically every special character, etc.) so that wouldn't really be a feasible option. @Thinkr

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406721/switch-layout-between-different-keyboards?rq=1

Comment: @only-a-user yes, but change the ***whole*** keyboard in both. It won't change the built-in one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406721/switch-layout-between-different-keyboards?rq=1) link, posted [in the comments](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/457836/can-i-specify-the-keyboard-layout-for-a-single-bluetooth-device#comment667974_457836), which ultimately points to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1143990/osx-automatically-change-input-source-for-different-keyboards/1150616#1150616) StackExchange issue, which resolves this problem using [this repository](https://github.com/ohueter/autokbisw). Follow the instructions provided and it should work.

The repository is called autokbisw by Ole Hüter. It works by automatically detecting which keyboard you are using and choosing the appropriate layout.

It can be installed via `brew`:

```bash
brew install ohueter/tap/autokbisw
brew services start ohueter/tap/autokbisw
```

Comment: Hello, only-a-user. This is considered a "link-only" answer. It would be helpful for future visitors to this question if you would [edit] in a summary of that page. Links can become broken or outdated so a summary would still provide the necessary information.